# mysql simple query took longer time

Tags: mysql, performance

```
select marksymbol,round(avg(p.closerate * p.out_share),2)
from price p
where trandate >= '2000/06/05' and trandate <= '2012/06/22' and p.markcode='RD'
group by marksymbol
```

It took 0.064s on a local machine with 2gb ram, it took 1 min 30.38 sec on the server.

I am running Windows on my local machine.
The server runs MySQL under Linux.

The database scheme is the same on both machines. They have the same indexes and primary keys.

What other factors could affect the performance of this query?

Comment: How much data do you have on the server?

Comment: do you install mysql manually? or just type the command and it installed by itself?

Comment: this has happened me a lot too lately. Don't know why!

Comment: Also its better if you ask this at http://dba.stackexchange.com/. May get proper explanation...

Answer (score 3):

They are indexed correctly, but are they the same size? Is the table on the Linux server significantly bigger than the table on the testing Windows server?

There are a few places you can look for which can help to solve the problem.

1 :  To the query itself, you EXPLAIN to let mysql tell you what is going on.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

If you have phpmyadmin installed than you can just click "explain" and it will do that automatically for you (with pretty pie chart) and you can identify the bottleneck that way.

2 : Memory usage on the server. Use the command

> free -m

and

> vmstat

to see how much memory is available. Your system could have been doing the expensive swapping for your query.

3: Optimize the query itself. From the look of it, you are using string comparison for date search. You can utilize the powerful Datetime feature in mysql to speed up your date comparison. However, I doubt this is the bottleneck for you, so check the top two options first.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try your suggested solution. In mean time i create the new table and copy the the existing table date to new table. Old table contain 1.8mn record. Then i run the same query on new table and it reply in in 8.43s.I do not know the reason i copy the structure with like command. If you have any suggestion to check to old table then let me know thanks

Comment: My guess is that maybe the table was heavily fragmented. Tried Optimize table? [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)